# Convert an Excel table from one structure to the other

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

## Original table

I have this table in Excel or LibreOffice.

| Unit number | Type | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Object | Top |
| 1 | Object | Bottom |
| 1 | Object | Left |
| 1 | Object | Right |
| 1 | Object | Back |
| 1 | Object | Front |
| 1 | Property | Right-Fixed |
| 1 | Property | Left-Fixed |
| 1 | Property | 4-legs |

## New table

I want to convert this table to a new one. I want to keep only the rows with the *Type* equal to *Object* and apply the *Properties* as new columns. Like below.

| Unit number | Type | Name | Right-fixed | Left-fixed | 4-legs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Object | Top |  |  |  |
| 1 | Object | Bottom |  |  | True |
| 1 | Object | Left |  | True |  |
| 1 | Object | Right | True |  |  |
| 1 | Object | Back |  |  |  |
| 1 | Object | Front |  |  |  |

## Question

How can I do that in Excel or LibreOffice? My options are:

- Formula-based approaches.

  - Will it get too complex?
- VBA macro programming.

  - Is it overkill for this problem?

I'd appreciate any hint or help.

## Note

Above, I have shown just the *Unit number* of `1` as a sample. But unit numbers could continue, like `2`, `3`, and more.

Comment: I'm studying the links provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71584381/3405291). Those are helpful user guides for Calc Basic code.

Comment: Do you know what all the properties are, i.e. could you create the appropriate property columns in advance?

Comment: Do you prefer LibreOffice or Excel solution? (They'd be similar, I'm sure.)

Comment: @ChrisDavies Yes, the properties are known up front.

Comment: @ChrisDavies I'd prefer LibreOffice of course :)

Answer (score 1):

Are there many properties?

I suggest you try following steps:

- Use formula like `=FILTER(A2:C10,B2:B10<>"Property")` to list all Type values.

[image]

- Use formula like `=IFERROR(IF(FIND("Right",C2)=1,"True",""),"")` for **Right** property,
- User formula like `=IFERROR(IF(FIND("Left",C2)=1,"True",""),"")` for **Left** property,
- Use formula like `=IFERROR(IF(FIND("Bottom",C2)=1,"True",""),"")` for **4-legs**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, let me test and try it...

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming there is no `Excel Constraints` then the following formula should work as per the tags posted. The following formula is a single input dynamic array formula.*

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _data, A2:C10,
     _object, FILTER(_data,INDEX(_data,,2)="Object"),
     _property, UNIQUE(TOROW(TAKE(FILTER(_data,INDEX(_data,,2)="Property"),,-1)),1),
     _rows, ROWS(_object),
     _cols, COLUMNS(_property),
     _name, SWITCH(LEFT(_property,2),"Ri","Ri","Le","Le","4-","Bo"),
     _convert, HSTACK(_object,MAKEARRAY(_rows,_cols,LAMBDA(r,c,N(INDEX(LEFT(TAKE(_object,,-1),2),r)=INDEX(_name,c))))),
     _headers, HSTACK(A1:C1,_property),
     VSTACK(_headers,_convert))
```

---

- `_data` --> variable used for the data range, excluding the headers,
- `_object` --> Using `FILTER()` returns the range which consists of only `object`
- `_property` --> Using `FILTER()` returns the range which consists of only `property`, and then taking the last column of that range with unique values transformed into columns from rows.
- `_rows` --> Using the `ROWS()` to get number of object rows count.
- `_cols` --> Using `COLUMNS()` to get the number of property columns count.
- `_name` --> Using the `SWITHC()` function amending the names so as to match with the properties.
- `_convert` --> This uses a combination of `HSTACK()` for one part and `MAKEARRAY()` for another part. So the `MAKEARRAY()` is returning an array with  `n` rows and `n` columns based on the custom `LAMBDA()` calculation applied, so what it does it just tries to do a `BOOLEAN LOGIC` and returns `1` for `TRUE` and `0` for `FALSE` which is custom formatted as `[=1]TRUE;;`. While using the `HSTACK()` we are combining the return value of `MAKEARRAY()` as well as the variable `_object`.
- `_headers` --> as the name defines returning the respective headers for the array.
- Lastly, using `VSTACK()` to append both the arrays, here `_headers` with `_convert`.

---

One small change can be done by removing the `_name` variable if you are sure about the property labels then,

• Instead of this

```
N(INDEX(LEFT(TAKE(_object,,-1),2),r)=INDEX(_name,c))
```

---

• Use this in place of that. remember to remove the `_name` variable first.

```
N(INDEX(TAKE(_object,,-1),r)=INDEX(TEXTBEFORE(SUBSTITUTE(_property,"4","Bottom"),"-"),c))
```

---

**Edit:**

Updated Formula which returns as per the desired output:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Data, A1:C19,
     _Mapping, {
         "Right-Fixed", "Right";
         "Left-Fixed", "Left";
         "4-Legs", "Bottom";
         "Front-Fixed", "Front";
         "Back-Fixed", "Back";
         "Folder", "Top"
      },
     _Headers, HSTACK(
         TAKE(_Data, 1),
         TOROW(
             TAKE(_Mapping, , 1)
         )
      ),
     _Object, FILTER(
         _Data,
         INDEX(_Data, , 2) =
             "Object"
     ),
     _Rows, ROWS(_Object),
     _Columns, COLUMNS(
         DROP(_Headers, , 3)
     ),
     _Matched, MAKEARRAY(_Rows,_Columns,LAMBDA(r,c, LET(
     _Property, FILTER(INDEX(_Data,,3),(INDEX(_Object,r,1)=INDEX(_Data,,1))*(INDEX(_Data,,2)="Property")),
     _MappedProps, VLOOKUP(_Property,_Mapping,2,0),
     _MappedObj, VLOOKUP(INDEX(DROP(_Headers,,3),c),_Mapping,2,0),
      N(OR((_MappedProps=_MappedObj)*(_MappedProps=INDEX(_Object,r,3))))))),
     _Merged, HSTACK(
         _Object,
         _Matched
      ),
     VSTACK(_Headers, _Merged)
     )
```

---

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try it out.

Comment: @Megidd refer the updated formula!

Comment: I will use macro programming. Thanks for this alternative.

Comment: @Megidd alright no issues. Cheer!

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table45"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Unit number", Int64.Type}, {"Type", type text}, {"Name", type text}}),

//Create list of all properties to use in the final expansion
    #"All Properties" = List.Distinct(Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Type]="Property")[Name]),

// for multiple units Group on unit
    #"Group Unit" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type",{"Unit number"}, {
        {"Props", (t)=>
            let 

            //List of Objects and Properties for this unit only
                Objects = Table.SelectRows(t, each [Type]="Object"),
                Properties = List.Distinct(Table.SelectRows(t, each [Type]="Property")[Name]),

            //Add Property columns to the Objects in the correct location
            //May need to change the logic of the `AddColumn` function depending on your
            //   actual data
                #"Add Property Columns" = List.Accumulate(
                    Properties,
                    Objects,
                    (s,c)=> Table.AddColumn(s,c, 
                        each if Text.StartsWith(c,[Name]) or (c = "4-legs" and [Name]="Bottom") then true else null, type logical))
            in
                #"Add Property Columns",
                type table[Unit number=Int64.Type, Type=text, Name=text,#"Right-Fixed"=logical, #"Left-Fixed", #"4-legs"=logical]}}),

//Remove unneeded column and expand the subtable
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Group Unit",{"Unit number"}),
    #"Expanded Props" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Props", 
        Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type") & #"All Properties")
in 
    #"Expanded Props"
```

***Original Data**
Showing two units*
[image]

***Results***
[image]

Comment: Sir there is one problem, it has `Folder` as `Property` as well, so the `Top` will show as `True` for `Folder`, will it be possible for you make the changes?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Any changes are simple to make, But where has the **OP** listed all of the properties and their relationships?

Comment: Sir, I have commented earlier here to post the same answer of yours in `StackOverflow` where OP has **[posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77884710/convert-an-excel-table-from-one-structure-to-the-other)** but since you were not replying so i deleted, Overthere they have accepted the way taller(vba guy) gave solution with relations to `6` properties & `6` objects. Before asking they have confirmed abt the number of properties, so i have asked you to amend, since this solution is also valuable like the formula. so we complete here with `PQ` , `DAF` & `VBA`!

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this alternative approach :)

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Again, the **OP** has not provided a list of possible properties and their relationships. In addition, in that thread it seems he is going to be converting to use a Macro in Libre Office. If he want to use the PQ approach, I would provide a more robust mapping solution once he clarifies the relationships.

Comment: Sir alright. Thanks!